# Errors when writing to stack in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I feel like it's not pointing to the address I want it to...

```
TwosLoop:
    bgt $t0, $a0, EndTwosLoop
    addi $t0, $t0, 2
    sw $0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    j TwosLoop
EndTwosLoop:
```

I'm trying to put a zero on every other value, but I think I end up pointing between values...

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe consider using a jump instruction that increments the word (4bytes), then jump back to your code that stores the zero value. That's the best advice I can give with the code you have now. Obviously not the most efficient way of going about it, but hopefully my thought process makes sense to you.

Comment: The error happens on the sw line, unaligned address

Comment: Figured out the issue. I, earlier in the code, subtracted 2 from the SP instead of a multiple of 4. Thanks user!

Comment: You need to have a register that stores an address. Your register currently points to zero. Make sense?

Comment: Cool. No problem. That always tripped me up too. Remember, a word is 4 bytes.

Answer (score -2):

You need to store an address to the register. Zero is pointed towards the register right now. There may be some arithmetical error earlier in the code. If you can send the whole code.

```
TwosLoop:
    bgt $t0, $a0, EndTwosLoop
    addi $t0, $t0, 2
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    j TwosLoop
EndTwosLoop:
```

Comment: `sp` does store an address, not zero; it's the stack pointer.  I think you just copy/pasted incorrect comments from the question.  You also removed the `sw` from the loop, so now it's not storing anything.  (But yes, the OP confirmed in comments they misaligned `sp` earlier.  The question itself still isn't a [mcve] and should just be deleted - the error message already says what the problem is, the question just didn't quote it.)